# Adding stripped line to string/array in Python

Tags: python, strip, readlines, startswith

I am a fairly new programmer.

I am currently trying to find data from .txt files and add them to a string or array, which will then eventually be added to a .csv file.

The data I am looking at are currently present in this form, numerous times at random intervals within each .txt file:

' Line Flux:                        3.0008e-19 +/- 2.6357e-21 [W/cm^2]'

Hence, after reading several ways around accessing this I have come up with a code that doesn't produce any errors, but doesn't print anything either:

```
cwd = os.getcwd()

def open_txt():
    flux = {}
    for file in cwd:
        if file.endswith('.txt'):
            f = open(file,'r')
            lines = f.readlines()
            for line in lines:
                if line.startswith(' Line Flux:'):
                    line.strip(' Line Flux:                        ' + '[W/cm^2]')
                    flux.append(line)
                    print flux

open_txt()
```

Is there anything glaringly obvious that I am doing incorrectly?

Thanks for reading. Any helpful replies would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if this is the only cause of your problem, but `strip` does not modify the string, it returns a brand new string with your desired changes. You have to assign the result to something if you want to use it.

Comment: Not the problem, but you are not closing the file. Put `f.close()` at the end of the method, or better, use `with open(file) as f:` to have it automatically closed.

Comment: also flux should be a list [] not a dict {}

Comment: Have you tried [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html), since you know the form of the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[getcwd](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html?highlight=getcwd#os.getcwd) returns a string, so i think this is where your bug is. You are iterating through each letter of the string. Perhaps you need [listdir](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir).

You may want to check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-to-list-all-files-of-a-directory-in-python) too.

---

If that is not the case you can try inserting the "print marker" and see if it opens a file at all

```
cwd = os.getcwd()

def open_txt():

    # This has to be a list, not a dict.
    flux = []
    for file in cwd:       

        if file.endswith('.txt'):
            # Check loop is entered, with this print marker
            print 'it opened file: %s'% file

            f = open(file,'r')
            lines = f.readlines()
            for line in lines:
                if line.startswith(' Line Flux:'):
                    line.strip(' Line Flux:                        ' + '[W/cm^2]')
                    flux.append(line)
                    print flux

open_txt()
```

---

Also, `strip` is removing all characters that you provided to it. Including `/ : e`. 
`strip('ab'+'cz')` is equivalent to `strip('acbz')`

Instead you can use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

```
import re

my_str = ' Line Flux: 3.0008e-19 +/- 2.6357e-21 [W/cm^2]'

pattern = re.compile(r'Line Flux: (.*?)\[W/cm\^2\]')
result = re.findall(pattern, my_str)

print result
```

Parenthesis in the pattern indicates which part of the match to be returned.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
cwd = os.getcwd()

def open_txt():
    flux = []
    for file in os.listdir(cwd):
        if file.endswith('.txt'):
            with open(file,'r') as f:
                lines = f.readlines()
                for line in lines:
                    if line.startswith(' Line Flux:'):
                        output_line = line[11:-8]
                        flux.append(output_line)
                print flux

open_txt()
```

I used with open to ensure the file is closed corretly.

Python slice notation to stip the first and last characters.

Changed flux to a list instead of dict.

I also moved the print statemnt out of the for loop so that it only prints the completed array.

Comment: I assumed (perhaps incorrectly) that you were trying to get the string with " Line Flux:" and  "[W/cm^2]" removed. If that is not the case a different strip method would be needed.